# Setting the id of an Ember component and handling click events

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am trying to implement a simple Ember component that has a dynamic `id` attribute and handles click events, but I'm having trouble doing both. If I set the `id` property, the click event doesn't fire; if I remove the dynamic `id` then click does fire.

I am setting the `id` as an attribute binding and I have a few other class name bindings.

Am I overwriting some Ember functionality by trying to set the `id` attribute of component? If so, how would you set a dynamic `id` attribute of the component?

Here's my `component.js`:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  active: false,
  elemId: "none",
  type: "none",
  click: function() {
    console.log("Clicked!!");
    return true;
  },

  tagName: 'span',
  classNames: ['annotation'],
  attributeBindings: ['id'],
  classNameBindings: ['typeClass', 'activeClass'],
  activeClass: function() {
    return this.get('active') ? `annotation-${this.get('type')}-active` : '';
  }.property('active'),
  typeClass: function() {
    return `annotation-${this.get('type')}`;
  }.property(),
  id: function() {
    return this.get('elemId');
  }.property()
});
```

I am currently using Ember v2.2.0.

Comment: Why do you need to use the id? Yes, it's essential for the event bubbling in ember to persist the id of an element.

Comment: @Microfed It's not essential I use the `id`. I will have a bunch of these on the page and I figured using the `id` was the appropriate way to uniquely identify each one.

Comment: `id` is almost never the best way to keep track of HTML elements, whether you're using Ember or not. The best way to keep track of HTML elements is to, well, keep track of them using themselves. Otherwise, you will spend the rest of your life worrying about IDs and setting them and using `getElementById` to get them back again, when you already had them in the first place.  if you show us how you are using the IDs, then maybe we could propose better ways to handle things.

Comment: Thanks guys. It's a bit tricky for me to show you exactly how I'm using them. I'm basically wanting to set the id of a component so further up the component tree I can attach/tether a floating popover to that component if needed. It feels like I'm fighting the framework a bit so I probably need to step back and rethink my approach.

Comment: Can you reproduce in [Ember Twiddle](http://ember-twiddle.com/)?

Comment: @CraigSketchley, you always can get a reference to the component itself in Javascript. And you shouldn't rely on DOM state while using Emberjs, mainly because Ember could change the DOM at any moment, and you can't predict and control it from outside. It's better to use templates and components hooks: https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.3.0/components/the-component-lifecycle/